# SSIS Foreaach Loop Container truncate table if there is any file

Tags: foreach, ssis, conditional-statements, truncate

I have foreach loop for excel files. The matter is I need truncate table and extract new rows only if there is any file. If not, process is being continued without foreash loop.
I configured control flow and data flow and it works if there are any file, but if don't I get an error.

[Control Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0UXZ.png)

I want to handle two situations: 1) When any file exists in directory -> truncate table and do data flow. 2) If directory is empty ( 0 .xlsx files) omit whole process and continue next tasks.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: You can use a script component to check a folder if there are any files. See https://www.techbrothersit.com/2013/07/ssis-how-to-check-if-file-exists-in.html?m=1